# php tags in string

Tags: php, xml

I'm trying to create an ArrayToXML converter in php.

I have this code:

```
function assocArrayToXML($root_element_name,$ar) {

         $xml = new SimpleXMLElement("<?xml version=\"1.0\"?><{$root_element_name}></{$root_element_name}>");

         $f = create_function('$f,$c,$a','
            foreach($a as $k=>$v) {
                       if(is_array($v)) {
                $ch=$c->addChild($k);
                $f($f,$ch,$v);
            } else {
                $c->addChild($k,$v);
            }
        }');
        $f($f,$xml,$ar);
        return $xml->asXML();
}
```

From http://php.net/manual/es/book.simplexml.php

The problem I have is this line:

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement("<?xml version=\"1.0\"?><{$root_element_name}></{$root_element_name}>");
```

Because the string has "?>" and the php "thinks" is the end of php tag.

How can I write this two character in a php string?

Comment: Are you sure, that it's considering it 'the end'? If so, try escaping it with a backslash?

Comment: which error are you getting? I think PHP is smarter than that...

Comment: You need to share your error, your code basically works unless an invalid root element name is provided (you don't check that). Demo: http://eval.in/11329

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear from your question where your problem is, you can use your code verbatim ([Demo](http://eval.in/11330)):

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement("<?xml version=\"1.0\"?><{$root_element_name}/>");
```

For simplexml this is actually equal to the following, shorter line (you might prefer):

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement("<{$root_element_name}/>");
```

SimpleXML adds the XML prologue on it's own, so you don't need to write it.

Escape the characters, so it becomes

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement("<?xml version=\"1.0\"?\><{$root_element_name}/>");
```

which is not needed but kept here becuase it was the original answer.

Comment: This answer is technically wrong. The characters do not need any escapes and the escapes provided are shady.

Comment: @hakre if you take out the \ you break the answer.  The problem is that php is reading <? as <?php

Comment: @user1389596: No it does not break anything if you take it out. Or about which concrete PHP version (not covered here) are you talking? Online demo: http://3v4l.org/mCHEJ

Comment: I've seen this exact problem on a server before, but I don't recall the version.  If it's a PHP issue, it is probably fixed in newest versions of PHP.  php.ini settings could also be a factor, if the script is set to interpret short <? ?> tags.

Answer (score 0):

Just split the string:

```
'<' . '?xml ....
```

Comment: not needed at all. http://3v4l.org/3VKBo

Comment: It's also possible to turn off php short tags in the php.ini.  Otherwise php can interpret it as a start tag.